# JavaScript Looping

Tags: javascript

I am having a bit of a problem with some JavaScript and PHP. The script (below) works exactly as wanted, but if I run it with the latest version of IE, the JavaScript appears to be looping and it makes the link flash, and it can only be stopped by closing the IE browser. 
In Firefox, it's probably doing the same, but without any flashing.
What I would like is a means of detecting that the JavaScript has already been run, and therefore shouldn't be run again.
The snippet below is part of a PHP script named prayer-times.php

```
<head>
    <script>
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var lat = position.coords.latitude
                var lon = position.coords.longitude
                document.location = "prayer-times.php?latitude=" + lat + "&longitude=" + lon
            });
        }
    </script>

<?php
    error_reporting(0);

    $lat = $_GET['latitude'];
    $lon = $_GET['longitude'];

        echo "Latitude: " . $lat . "<br/>";
        echo "Longitude: " . $lon . "<br/>";
?>
```

I'm really hoping that there is an expert out somewhere who can offer a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning to `document.location` on *every page load*. That refreshes the browser. You need to conditionally *not* do that, if the latitude and longitude are the same as those already being passed to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Latitude and Longitude have a value in you PHP.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['latitude']){
   if (empty($_GET['latitude'])){ ?>
      // javascript code
   <?php }
}?>
```